# How to trace values of a recursive PureScript function in the repl?

Tags: purescript

With this `Main.purs` (excluding imports):

```
main :: Effect Unit
main = pure foo

foo :: Unit
foo = trace "foo" (\_ -> unit)
```

This works as expected with both `pulp repl` and `pulp run`:

```
> import Main
> foo
'foo'
unit

> :q
See ya!
$ pulp run
* Building project in ...
* Build successful.
'foo'
$
```

But with this `Main.purs` I get different results with `pulp repl` and `pulp run`:

```
main :: Effect Unit
main = pure $ bar unit

bar :: Unit -> Unit
bar _ = trace "bar" (\_ -> bar unit)
```

`pulp repl`:

```
> import Main
> bar unit
console.js:168
    if (isStackOverflowError(e))
        ^
```

`pulp run`:

```
$ pulp run
* Building project in ...
* Build successful.
'bar'
'bar'
... omitted ...
'bar'
'bar'
'bar'
console.js:168
    if (isStackOverflowError(e))
        ^
```

I also discovered this odd behavior which may or may not be related:

`Main.purs`:

```
main :: Effect Unit
main = pure unit

-- foo is dead code
foo :: Unit
foo = trace "foo" (\_ -> unit)
```

Shell:

```
$ pulp run
* Building project in ...
* Build successful.
'foo'
```

Comment: With recursive case - I already answered you in the other question: it's a problem with REPL, it swallows console output sometimes. With the last example - what problem do you see in it?

Comment: Yeah I think this last case is just strict evaluation.